# How to run any interactive program before sign in to windows or before login?

Tags: operating-system, windows-services, autologin

Basically I want to send Windows Credentials at windows login screen and make it to send password in Password Box and click on login button automatically.
Am making a Project where I need to implement auto login system, when I send Password to windows a program should be there at windows logon screen to receive inputs and send to password entry and click on login button.

Answer (score 0):

Windows Security DONOT allow any problem running before winlogon

You may be needed to write a driver as a HID device,and type password in time.

Check out it in learn.microsoft.com